switching 2 mosfets with 1 signal

Hi. I'm trying to switch between 2 LED with 1 GPIO and not sure if I've designed correctly.
C2_CC_CTRL = GPIO
i wonder when GPIO signal is "high", Q14 MOSFET = "ON", D29 LED = "ON", SW12 Relay = "LOW"
Q13 MOSFET = "OFF", D27 LED "OFF".
Please let me know if I've missed any information to present.

Designed correctly means what do you expect the inputs to that circuit be. How are the resistor values determined? Have you simulated the circuit? Why is the relay flipping pins of Type-C CC wires?

I've checked resistor values considering pre-existing circuits from my company which were designed long time ago and the designer isn't here anymore. and originally the circuit had only one MOSFET ,one LED and only NO contact for the relay. now I wanted to modify it to also indicate NC contact with only 1 GIPO signal.

Do we have to guess the notation? E.g is that really a 332 ohm resistor, or 3.3 kohm?
